# Typing a constrained dictionary with TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, immutable.js

I have a TypeScript 2.0 project where I'd like to define an immutable **Map** using `Immutable.js`. In particular I'd like to constrain the keys of the Map to a known set; something like the following:

```
type ConstrainedKeys = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz';
interface INameValuePair {
    name: string;
    value: string;
};
const dictionary = Immutable.Map<ConstrainedKeys, NameValuePair>(response);
```

Where the `response` might be something like:

```
{
    foo: {
        name: 'foo',
        value: 'typing is fun'
    }
}
```

But when I try and reference `dictionary.foo.value` I get the Typescript error:

> [ts] Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'Map<ConstrainedKeys,INameValuePair>'.

Comment: You get that error when doing what? Are you trying to access `foo` like this: `dictionary.foo`?

Comment: Sorry, yes. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: You may also check out https://github.com/engineforce/ImmutableAssign, which is a lightweight immutable helper that supports TypeScript type checking, and allows you to continue working with POJO (Plain Old JavaScript Object).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Immutable.Map` instances don't have properties for the entries, you need to access them like so:

```
let foo = dictionary.get("foo");
```

If you want to be able to access it like `dictionary.foo` then you need to change the instances yourself, or you can use a [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy):

```
const map = Immutable.Map<ConstrainedKeys, INameValuePair>({
    foo: {
        name: 'foo',
        value: 'typing is fun'
    }
});

const dictionary = new Proxy(map, {
    get: (target: Immutable.Map<ConstrainedKeys, INameValuePair>, name: ConstrainedKeys) => {
        if ((target as any)[name]) {
            return (target as any)[name];
        }
        return target.get(name);
    }
}) as Immutable.Map<ConstrainedKeys, INameValuePair> & { foo: INameValuePair };

console.log(dictionary.foo); // {name: "foo", value: "typing is fun"}
console.log(dictionary.get("foo")); // {name: "foo", value: "typing is fun"}
```

Comment: Thanks Nitzan; very new to Immutable so thanks for your patience on my newbie question.